# Installing Mojito in windows

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, yahoo, mojito

I want to install Mojito in Windows.  I have MinGW and nodejs in Windows.  But I am not able to install Mojito using `npm install -g mojito`.  It gives the following error on installing in windows

```
npm WARN package.json connect@1.8.2 No README.md file found!
npm WARN engine connect@1.8.2: wanted: {"node":">= 0.4.1 < 0.7.0"} (current: {"node":"0.8.3","npm":"1.1.43"})
npm WARN engine express@2.5.2: wanted: {"node":">= 0.4.1 < 0.7.0"} (current: {"node":"0.8.3","npm":"1.1.43"})
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 53,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: yui3@0.7.12
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin,linux
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: ia32

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! stack Error: Unsupported
npm ERR! stack     at checkPlatform (c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install.js:747:14)
npm ERR! stack     at Array.1 (c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\bind-actor.js:15:8)
npm ERR! stack     at LOOP (c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\chain.js:15:14)
npm ERR! stack     at c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\chain.js:18:7
npm ERR! stack     at checkEngine (c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install.js:726:10)
npm ERR! stack     at Array.0 (c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\bind-actor.js:15:8)
npm ERR! stack     at LOOP (c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\chain.js:15:14)
npm ERR! stack     at chain (c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\chain.js:20:5)
npm ERR! stack     at installOne_ (c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install.js:692:3)
npm ERR! stack     at installOne (c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install.js:615:3)
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.0.7
```

In Yahoo Developer [Website](http://developer.yahoo.com/cocktails/mojito/docs/quickstart/) it is mentioned clearly that  Unix-based system is a Prerequisites, but is it possible to install it on windows by using cygwin or mingw.

Answer (score 0):

It's an open issue, sorry about that.
Add yourself to https://github.com/yahoo/mojito/issues/264 to keep track of our progress.